# Using for loop to move files from subdirectories to parent directories

Tags: linux, unix, for-loop

I just made the switch to linux and I am trying to write my first bash script. I have a folder that contains numerous folders, all with subfolders containing files. Something like:

- MainFolder

  - Folder1

    - Sub1 (Contains many files)
    - Sub2 (Contains many files)
  - Folder2

    - Sub1 (Contains many files)
    - Sub2 (Contains many files)

  .
  .
  .

I want to move all the files contained in the sub-folders to the their parent folders. My first instinct is to try and write a for-loop. I was able to do one folder at a time with the command:

```
mv MainFolder/Folder1/*/* MainFolder/Folder1/
```

But I was hoping to write a bash script to loop over all the folders in the main directory. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="/pathto/MainFolder"

subs= ls $dir1

for i in $subs; do
  mv "$dir1/$i/*/*" "$dir1/$i/" 
done
```

This, obviously, does not work, but I do not understand where I am going wrong.

I also tried:

```
mv MainFolder/*/*/* MainFolder/*/
```

with pretty disastrous results. Once I get the file move working properly, I would also like to delete the old sub folders within the loop.

Comment: What do you want to do with `MainFolder/Folder1/Sub1/foo.txt` and `MainFolder/Folder1/Sub2/foo.txt`? Are you ok with destroying some of your files when there are name conflicts?

Comment: In my scenario there will not be any name conflicts, but I would be interested in how one might handle that.

Comment: That would be for you to decide - there are many ways to deal with it, with the two obvious ones being 1) don't move the second and subsequent conflicting files and 2) somehow rename all the conflicts so they don't conflict. But it really depends on what you want to accomplish...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small change. change

```
subs=ls $dir1
```

to

```
subs=`ls $dir1`
```

Notice the backquotes. Backquotes actually execute the bash command and return the result. If you issue `echo $subs` after the line, you'll find that it correctly lists `folder1`, `folder2`.

Second small change is to remove double quotes in the `mv` command. Change them to

```
mv $dir1/$i/*/* $dir1/$i
```

Double quotes take literal file names while removing quotes takes the recursive directory pattern.

After that, your initial for loop is indeed correct. It will move everything from `sub1` and `sub2` to `folder1` etc.

Comment: Processing "ls" in the manner described by the accepted answer introduces pitfalls, including choking on directory names that contain spaces. See, e.g., https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 AND https://superuser.com/questions/1191472/move-each-file-into-its-parent-directory-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is working solution

```
#!/bin/bash

mainDir="$(dirname $(realpath $0))/store/media"

subs=`ls $mainDir`

for i in $subs; do
    if [[ -d "$mainDir/$i" ]]; then
        mv "$mainDir/$i"/* "$mainDir/"
        rm -rf "$mainDir/$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: /store/media" should be removed and the script run at the same level of the sub folders

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

dir1="/pathto/MainFolder"

subs=`ls $dir1`

for i in $subs; do

mv $dir1/$i/*/* $dir1/$i

done