# How to move files from subfolders to their parent directory (unix, terminal)

Tags: bash, unix, filesystems, subdirectory, file-move

I have a folder structure like this:
A big parent folder named Photos. This folder contains 900+ subfolders named a_000, a_001, a_002 etc.

Each of those subfolders contain more subfolders, named dir_001, dir_002 etc. And each of those subfolders contain lots of pictures (with unique names).

I want to move all these pictures contained in the subdirectories of a_xxx inside a_xxx. (where xxx could be 001, 002 etc)

After looking in similar questions around, this is the closest solution I came up with:

```
for file in *; do
  if [ -d $file ]; then
    cd $file; mv * ./; cd ..; 
  fi
done
```

Another solution I got is doing a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1="/path/to/photos/"
subs= `ls $dir1`

for i in $subs; do
  mv $dir1/$i/*/* $dir1/$i/ 
done
```

Still, I'm missing something, can you help?

(Then it would be nice to discard the empty dir_yyy, but not much of a problem at the moment)

Comment: You should probably be asking this in the unix linix  SE, as it is not really a programming question.   But as a hint, doing something inside  each a_xxx directory like `find . -type f -exec mv \{\} . \;`  could be what you are looking for

Comment: Hi. I have 900+ folders, no way I'm gonna do this to each of them. I'm sorry if SO is not the place to post. It's that here i found the more relevant examples: [link1] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546294/copy-files-from-subfolders-to-the-nearest-parent-directory-in-unix) and [link2] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228718/using-for-loop-to-move-files-from-subdirectories-to-parent-directories)

Comment: sure about `mv * ./;` part? because it seems to me that two points (for parent directory) would be needed somewhere, like `mv * ../;` perhaps

Comment: Nope, not sure at all... I have no idea of bash scripting. Gonna try slightly different versions to see what happens.

Comment: The thing is you actually have two searches to do, one to iterate through your a_xxx directors, and then another within each of those to move the data files up into the particular a_xxx directory.  It's difficult to do that with one command.   Moving them all to one place would be much easier

Comment: Ehm. All the provided solutions do the job....Thank you guys. I wish I could give a star to each one of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

#needed in case we have empty folders
shopt -s nullglob

#we must write the full path here (no ~ character)
target="/path/to/photos"

#we use a glob to list the folders. parsing the output of ls is baaaaaaaddd !!!!
#for every folder in our photo folder ... 
for dir in "$target"/*/
do
    #we list the subdirectories ...
    for sub in "$dir"/*/
    do
        #and we move the content of the subdirectories to the parent
        mv "$sub"/* "$dir"
        #if you want to remove subdirectories once the copy is done, uncoment the next line
        #rm -r "$sub"
    done
done
```

[Here is why you don't parse ls in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory where the files exist is correct (and complete) in the following script and try it:

```
#!/bin/bash
BigParentDir=Photos

for subdir in "$BigParentDir"/*/; do    # Select the a_001, a_002 subdirs
  for ssdir in "$subdir"/*/; do         # Select dir_001, … sub-subdirs
    for f in "$ssdir"/*; do             # Select the files to move
      if [[ -f $f ]]; do                # if indeed are files
         echo \
         mv "$ssdir"/* "$subdir"/       # Move the files.
      fi
    done
  done      
done
```

No file will be moved, just printed. If you are sure the script does what you want, comment the echo line and run it "for real".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1="/path/to/photos/"
subs= `ls $dir1`

cp /dev/null /tmp/newscript.sh

for i in $subs; do
  find $dir1/$i -type f -exec echo mv \'\{\}\' $dir1/$i \; >> /tmp/newscript.sh
done
```

then open `/tmp/newscript.sh` with an editor or `less` and see if looks like what you are trying to do.

if it does then execute it with `sh -x /tmp/newscript.sh`